# Valor de campo por programación

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

estoy haciendo mis primeros pasos en Django. Quiero que me grabe en la tabla paises (en el campo 'otro') un valor por programación que depende de la condición POST (si POST es update, otro = '11' (como estaba antes) sino otro = '22').
Sin que aparezca en el formulario.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import PaisForm
from Superior.Apps.Secretaria.models import Profesores, paises

def Home(request):
   return render(request,'Secretaria\index.html')

def CrearPais(request):
   i_paises = paises()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       pais_form = PaisForm(request.POST)
       if pais_form.is_valid():
           pais_form.save()
           return redirect('index')
    else:
        pais_form = PaisForm()
    return render(request,'Secretaria/crear_pais.html'{'pais_form':pais_form})
```

alguien me puede orientar. 
gracias.

Comment: No me queda clara la condición que quieres utilizar.. si POST es update?
De todas formas echa un vistazo a esta web, que es un pequeño tutorial para crear una app crud con django.

Comment: quiero que cuando cargo los datos de un pais en un formulario y graba deje tal cual estaba el campo "otro", y en el caso de agregar un pais, el campo "otro" no se cargue visualmente sino por programación con cualquier valor.

Comment: Cuando renderizas la view puedes hacer que en el formulario se pinte la info que tu quieras. Recuperas el formulario en el método get y lo pasas a través de la variable context (context='formulario': formulario}, también puedes recuperar el formulario en la view y extraer los datos que quieras para pintarlo en el template. (context='dato_que_quiero_pintar': dato_que_quiero_pintar'), recuerda que a través de la variable request puedes acceder al usuario que realiza la petición y así recuperar todos los datos asociados a ese usuario.